# Transparent Form with Visible Clickable Controls in it

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8, windows-8.1, setwindowlong

I'm trying to make a mouse transparent form in win8 and winforms, that contains controls that are clickable.

I'm able to make the form mouse transparent, using this code

```
int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);
```

(on win8 the WndProc approach does not work)

But when I make the form mouse transparent, the controls that are contained in this form are also mouse transparent

What can I do?

Comment: what do you mean by 'mouse transparent' ?

Comment: I mean that the mouse events will "pass  through" the form to whatever behind it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Form and set both `BackColor` and `TransparencyKey` properties to `Color.Magenta`.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Click pass through window and reaches to what behind it, but of you click on button 1, button will be clicked.

**Note:**
 The trick works for some colors, for example if you use Color.Red it will be transparent but handles clicks, but using Magenta the form will be mouse transparent too.