# Set the form region to the bounds of its child controls in C# or VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, gdi+

I started to create a generic usage/reusable method that will help to set the region of a Form to the bounds of its child controls.

But I found a problem when the rectangle of a control intersects with another, I mean the Z-Order, when a control is in front of other and covers a part of the other control in the background, in these circunstances the rectangle of the control in the front is not properly drawn...

See:

[image]

...where Button2 is in front of Button1.

Probably is my fault with the usage of the `GraphicsPath` class to draw the region path, because I'm not experienced using GDI+ in this way, and maybe I'm writting bad the path...

How can I fix this code to set the expected region?.

Here is the code. Before use it, set the `FormBorderStyle` property to `None` (a borderless form).

VB.NET:

```
Public Shared Sub LockFormRegionToControls(ByVal f As Form)
    LockFormRegionToControls(Of Control)(f)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub LokckFormRegionToControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal f As Form)

    Dim rects As Rectangle() =
        (From ctrl As T In f.Controls.OfType(Of T)
         Order By f.Controls.GetChildIndex(ctrl) Ascending
         Select ctrl.Bounds).ToArray()

    Using path As New GraphicsPath()
        path.AddRectangles(rects)
        f.Region = New Region(path)
    End Using

End Sub
```

C#:

```
public static void LockFormRegionToControls(Form f) {
    LockFormRegionToControls<Control>(f);
}

public static void LockFormRegionToControls<T>(Form f) where T : Control {

    Rectangle[] rects = (
        from T ctrl in f.Controls.OfType<T>()
        orderby f.Controls.GetChildIndex(ctrl) ascending
        select ctrl.Bounds).ToArray();

    using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath()) {
        path.AddRectangles(rects);
        f.Region = new Region(path);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can not see what stops you from using `Color.Magena` as `BackColor` and `TransparencyKey`. This way the area around controls will be transparent and will be deleted from region of the form and will not receive clicks, while the controls will remain clickable. Take a look at this post: [Winforms mouse transparent form with clickable controls in it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32920402/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a border-less form it is pretty simple (no offset to client area).  Just start with an empty region and union in the control bounds.

```vb
Public Shared Sub LockFormRegionToControls(ByVal f As Form)
    Dim r As New Region()
    r.MakeEmpty()
    For Each c As Control In f.Controls
        Using r2 As New Region(c.Bounds)
            r.Union(r2)
        End Using
    Next
    Dim oldRegion As Region = f.Region
    f.Region = r
    If oldRegion IsNot Nothing Then oldRegion.Dispose()
End Sub
```

---

Edit:  Method to handle non-client areas of form with border.

```
Public Shared Sub LockFormRegionToControls(ByVal f As Form)
    ' determine offset to client rectangle
    Dim zero As Point = f.PointToScreen(Point.Empty) ' top-left of client rectangle in screen coordinates
    Dim offsetX As Int32 = zero.X - f.Location.X
    Dim offsetY As Int32 = zero.Y - f.Location.Y

    ' region for entire form including non-client
    Dim r As New Region(New Rectangle(0, 0, f.Width, f.Height))

    Dim clientRect As Rectangle = f.ClientRectangle
    ' this rect is located at 0,0 so apply the offset
    clientRect.Offset(offsetX, offsetY)

    ' subtract the client rectangle
    r.Exclude(clientRect)

    ' now add in the control bounds
    For Each c As Control In f.Controls
        Dim b As Rectangle = c.Bounds
        ' controlBounds are relative to the client rectangle, so need to offset
        b.Offset(offsetX, offsetY)
        Using r2 As New Region(b)
            r.Union(r2)
        End Using
    Next

    Dim oldRegion As Region = f.Region
    f.Region = r
    If oldRegion IsNot Nothing Then oldRegion.Dispose()
End Sub
```

---

Edit 2: Thin border adjustment.

```
Public Shared Sub LockFormRegionToControls(ByVal f As Form)
    ' determine offset to client rectangle
    Dim zero As Point = f.PointToScreen(Point.Empty) ' top-left of client rectangle in screen coordinates
    Dim offsetX As Int32 = zero.X - f.Location.X
    Dim offsetY As Int32 = zero.Y - f.Location.Y

    ' simulate thin border
    Dim occludedBorderOffset As Int32 = Math.Max(offsetX - 2, 0)
    Dim whAdjustment As Int32 = 2 * occludedBorderOffset

    ' region for entire form including non-client
    Dim mainRect As New Rectangle(occludedBorderOffset, occludedBorderOffset, f.Width - whAdjustment, f.Height - whAdjustment)

    Dim r As New Region(mainRect)

    Dim clientRect As Rectangle = f.ClientRectangle
    ' this rect is located at 0,0 so apply the offset
    clientRect.Offset(offsetX, offsetY)

    ' subtract the client rectangle
    r.Exclude(clientRect)

    ' now add in the control bounds
    For Each c As Control In f.Controls
        Dim b As Rectangle = c.Bounds
        ' ontrolBounds are relative to the client rectangle, so need to offset
        b.Offset(offsetX, offsetY)
        Using r2 As New Region(b)
            r.Union(r2)
        End Using
    Next

    Dim oldRegion As Region = f.Region
    f.Region = r
    If oldRegion IsNot Nothing Then oldRegion.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem now is if I add the bounds of the titlebar too. For example in a Sizeable normal form, I know the titlebar bounds (including the border size) so I adjust the X and Y properties of each control rectangle bounds, and the resulting region with all the unions made are drawn perfect, however,if with all the rectangle offsets adjusted I also add a new region union for the titlebar bounds,then the region moves a little to the left in all the controls,I don't know why. Maybe you could guide me with a hint of what Im doing wrong, without the need to publish another question?.

Comment: Yes I didn't wanted to make more complicated/boring to read my question, for that reason I only specified borderless form, on which is simpler to reproduce the code. Please see this if you would, to understand what I mean (it is a sizeable form): https://i.imgur.com/0wmk8Za.png  + https://i.imgur.com/7F0io6f.png

Comment: It works except for the right and bottom edges borders of the form, if you put a control near the right edge, the region will include part of the border. I think 'clientRect' width and height needs some calc readjustment before excluding it in the region. But don't worry don't do more, I can't ask you for more, many thanks for all your help! with that code maybe I can follow tomorrow and fix the issue with 'clientRect'.

Comment: @ElektroStudios, don't worry about asking things.  You, unlike many people these days, appreciate the help people offer and that is all I can expect.  It may appear to be off on a Win 8+ system due to way form borders are draw with a thin line now.  When you apply a region, the full border thickness shows.  I seem to recall that there is some system metric you can query to get that info, but it eludes me at this moment.  I updated the code to simulate a thin border (2 px) its just simple math.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a C# implementation of the method **TnTinMn** coded.
(Since both C# and VB.Net tags are shown here, it may be useful).

Call `LockFormRegionToControls(TestForm, [IsBorderless]);` with true or false.

```
//The Form is not Borderless
LockFormRegionToControls(TestForm, false);


    public static void LockFormRegionToControls(Form f, bool IsBorderless) {
            LockBLFormRegionToControls<Control>(f, IsBorderless);
    }

    public static void LockBLFormRegionToControls<T>(Form f, bool Borderless) where T : Control
    {
        Region NewRegion;
        Point OffSet = Point.Empty;

        if (Borderless)
        {
            NewRegion = new Region();
        } else {
            OffSet = new Point((f.Bounds.Width - f.ClientSize.Width) / 2, f.Bounds.Height - f.ClientSize.Height);
            NewRegion = new Region(f.Bounds);
        }

        foreach (T ctrl in f.Controls.OfType<T>()) {
            Point p = new Point(ctrl.Bounds.Left + OffSet.X, ctrl.Bounds.Y + (OffSet.Y - OffSet.X));
            Size s = new Size(ctrl.Bounds.Width, ctrl.Bounds.Height);
            NewRegion.Union(new Region(new Rectangle(p, s)));
        }

        f.Region = NewRegion;
    }
```