# WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP messages are not received in the WndProc for filled rectangles

Tags: c#, winforms, wndproc

I have made a semi-transparent, borderless form with a resizable transparent panel in the middle. To do this, overriding the `OnPaint`, I painted dashed borders and boxes around the panel using `e.Graphics.DrawLines(...)`, `e.Graphics.FillRectangles(...)`, and `e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(...)` methods. I then handled the `WM_NCHITTEST` and `WM_MOUSEMOVE` in the `WndProc` as below.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    bool handled = false;

    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        if (...) // any of the boxes contains the client-point
        {
            m.Result = (IntPtr)HT; // HT can be HTLEFT = 10, HTRIGHT = 11, and so on
            handled = true;
        }
    }

    if (!handled)
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

[image: The resizable transparent panel in the middle of a semi-transparent borderless form]

So far so good—the dashed borders and the boxes filled with a white brush pass the hit test successfully. Now, I also need to handle the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` messages in the `WndProc`. It seems the `WndProc` receives either of these messages only when the pointer is over the borders of the panel (i.e., drawn with the `e.Graphics.DrawLines(...)`) or the borders of the boxes (i.e., drawn with the `e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(...)`) but not when the mouse pointer is over the filled area of the boxes (i.e., filled with the `e.Graphics.FilledRectangles(...)`). Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    bool handled = false;

    if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN || m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        // unreachable for the filled rectangles!?
    }

    if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        ...
    }

    if (!handled)
        base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Inspired by @l33t, I added the following line to the `WndProc` to monitor all messages.

```
Debug.WriteLine($"m.Msg = {m.Msg}");
```

Here is the list of all the messages received.

```
const uint WM_SIZE = 0x0005;                // 5  
const uint WM_GETTEXT = 0x000d;             // 13 
const uint WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000e;       // 14 
const uint WM_PAINT = 0x000f;               // 15 
const uint WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x0014;          // 20 
const uint WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020;           // 32 
const uint WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021;       // 33 
const uint WM_CHILDACTIVATE = 0x0022;       // 34 
const uint WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x0024;       // 36 
const uint WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046;   // 70 
const uint WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 0x0047;    // 71 
const uint WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x0083;          // 131
const uint WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;           // 132
const uint WM_NCPAINT = 0x0085;             // 133
const uint WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 0x00a0;         // 160
const uint WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00a1;       // 161
const uint WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 0x00a2;         // 162
const uint WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00a3;     // 163
const uint WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = 0x00a4;       // 164
const uint WM_NCRBUTTONUP = 0x00a5;         // 165
const uint WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00a6;     // 166
const uint WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN = 0x00a7;       // 167
const uint WM_NCMBUTTONUP = 0x00a8;         // 168
const uint WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00a9;     // 169
const uint WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN = 0x00ab;       // 171
const uint WM_NCXBUTTONUP = 0x00ac;         // 172
const uint WM_NCXBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00ad;     // 173
const uint WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;             // 273
const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;          // 274
const uint WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;           // 512     
const uint WM_NEXTMENU = 0x0213;            // 531
const uint WM_SIZING = 0x0214;              // 532
const uint WM_CAPTURECHANGED = 0x0215;      // 533
const uint WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE = 0x0231;       // 561
const uint WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232;        // 562
```

It turned out that `WM_NCLBUTTONUP` was not received either. I found the `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` being received at the end of any operations on the drawn objects.

Comment: How did you make the box area fully transparent? Are you relying on transparency key of the form? For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32921556/3110834), if you use Color.Red as transparency key, it handles the clicks, but if you use Color.Magenta, it will be mouse-transparent as well.

Comment: It would be better if you share the whole code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, I used the transparency key of the form, being `Green`.

Comment: Thanks Reza. Sure, I now update the question to include the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess; try [WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nclbuttondown) and [WM_NCLBUTTONUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nclbuttonup) instead.

If that doesn't help, try running [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2022) to see which mouse messages are in fact sent. Also, handling mouse messages that do *not* belong to your own window (i.e. the `Desktop`) requires a [mouse hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_mouse).

Comment: I now know where to look for a clue :)

Comment: I had a problem WM_LBUTTONUP sometimes called, sometimes not, then I replaced WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP with WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN and WM_NCLBUTTONUP, my problem finally solved, Thank You Brother.